# HTML CSS doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, less

I have following code, that works well in Chrome and FireFox but doesn't work in Safari.

Could you please help me investigate what is going on and how do I make it compatible for Safari and other browsers?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dashadasha/pen/VvYZxN)

Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

LESS:

```
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.time-slice {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-left: 20px;
  > * {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-color: #29a8bb;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 91px;
  z-index:2;
  > .circle {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
  }
}

.date-time {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.time-slice.row:not(:last-child)  .point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top:0;
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
}

.duration {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="time-slice row">
    <div class="date-time">
      <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
      <p class="time">10:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="point-title">
      <span>
      <b>Kiev Borispol (KBP)</b>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="time-slice row">
        <div class="date-time">
          <p class="time duration">1h 30min</p>
        </div>
        <div class="point-title">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="time-slice row">
    <div class="date-time">
      <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
      <p class="time">10:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="point-title">
      <span>
      <b>Amsterdam (AMS)</b>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks! It works then I open your url in the Safari. I am using Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25). What do I need to change in my project in order to see change on localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using all the correct vendor prefixes?

Prefixed [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GpgRjj) that works in Chrome, Edge & FF That's usually the problem with Safari.

If you click on the "View Compiled" button you will see the full CSS. Codepen uses a couple of optional tools (autoprefixer or prefixfree) to manage this. Click on the CSS Cog to see the options available

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.time-slice {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.time-slice > * {
  padding: 20px;
}
.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-color: #29a8bb;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 91px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.circle-wrap > .circle {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
.date-time {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.time-slice.row:not(:last-child) .point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
.duration {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="time-slice row">
    <div class="date-time">
      <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
      <p class="time">10:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="point-title">
      <span>
      <b>Kiev Borispol (KBP)</b>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="time-slice row">
    <div class="date-time">
      <p class="time duration">1h 30min</p>
    </div>
    <div class="point-title">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="time-slice row">
    <div class="date-time">
      <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
      <p class="time">10:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="point-title">
      <span>
      <b>Amsterdam (AMS)</b>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Safari needs the `-webkit` prefix for all flex properties. Try adding this to the css:

```
.time-slice {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
}

.date-time {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
}
```